# Detect mouse speed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, mouse, detect

I want to detect mouse speed, for example the event will be fired only if the detected number is greater than 5

I found one example which I think is something similar: http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/49/capturing-cursor-speed/

but i am not able to make it see the number which is inside div and fire the event based on the resulting number, this is my attempt:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cursometer.1.0.0.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function() {

var $speedometer = $('#speedometer');

$('#test-area').cursometer({
    onUpdateSpeed: function(speed) {
        $speedometer.text(speed);
    },
    updateSpeedRate: 20
});




    $("#test-area").mouseover(function(){

    if(this.value > 5) {
        console.log("asdasd");
    }

    else {
        console.log("bbb");
    }



})

});

</script>

<style>
#test-area
{
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="test-area"></div>
<div id="speedometer"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your html code  .

Comment: Thank you Tushar I just posted my html

Comment: see this demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/edUVs/51/

Comment: thank you Tushar and this is the results I got as well, the problem is that it does not detect the condition of the number, I want the event to fire only if the number is greater than 5, plus it only works on "else" statement and nothing is fired on "if"

Answer (score 1):

(I'm the author of the plug-in that's causing the trouble here)

The example isn't working because `this.value` isn't referring to the speed (it's `undefined`). Here's an updated version of your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eY6Z9/

It would probably be more efficient to store the speed value in a variable rather than within the text value of an HTML element. Here’s an updated version with that enhancement:
http://jsfiddle.net/eY6Z9/2/

Hope that helps!